# Connecting Azure SQL to local external table Error: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred

Tags: sql-server, azure, external-tables

In SSMS, from a query window in an Azure SQL database, I'm trying to select data from external tables in a local SQL server.  I'm getting the following error:

```
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)'.
```

I've created definitions for external tables to my local SQL Server.  The table definitions properties show the correct data source and you can see the data source definitions:

```
data_source_id  name    location    type_desc   type    resource_manager_location   credential_id    
database_name   shard_map_name  connection_options  pushdown
65537   eternareport    localhost   RDBMS   1   NULL    65537   eternareport    NULL    NULL    ON
```

And scoped credentials:

```
name    principal_id    credential_id   credential_identity create_date modify_date target_type target_id
ExternalReportingDBCredential   1   65537   sa  2020-12-14 15:32:19.983 2020-12-14 15:32:19.983 NULL    NULL
```

For the location I've tried localhost, internal ip (10.0.0.12), and external IP... added :1433, tcp://, mssql://, all with same results.  I've created other external tables but within different databases but all on Azure SQL, not localhost.

I have both the localhost and Azure SQL db's open in SSMS and access both with SQL authentication.  I'm not sure what else I'm forgetting.

NOTE: Could this be an issue with the "Trust Server Certificate" option?  I seem to remember checking that before.

Comment: Do your local server have public network IP?

Comment: Yes, as I said above, "I've tried localhost, internal ip (10.0.0.12), and external IP... "

Comment: It seems that there is NAT(Network Address Translation) between private IP and public IP or the `LOCATION` is wrong, it's format need to be `xx.xx.xx.xx,1433`.

Answer (score 0):

You also can reference [communicate with on-premises resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-overview) via Azure V-Net and create [Point-to-site VPN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/point-to-site-about?toc=/azure/virtual-network/toc.json#). So that your Azure SQL External tables can connect to your local SQLServer.